# Parse Log using Linq to text

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parsing, logging

I have an example log that i am trying to find the best solution to get me pieces of information: Mainly `time stamp` and a specific string.

Example Log Output: Each are on 1 Line

```
####<Jun 22, 2012 12:54:18 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <lname> <dname> <main>
<<WLS Kernel>> <> <BEA-000360> <Application started in RUNNING mode>
```

Each log line has the 4 beginning `#` tag followed by `<Timestamp>` all pieces that are relevant to my scenario have the `<>` enclosed brackets and i want to have an array of information where the index is based on left to right reads.

For each `<>` bracket, i want to store its information in the lineArray.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Projects\test.txt"))
{
    foreach(var line in ReadLines(reader)) 
    {
          //add logic to parse and read info into brackets
        String sLine = (String)line;
        String splitD = sLine.Split("<>")[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not a regexp guru, but this should work:

```
string test = "####<Jun 22, 2012 12:54:18 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <lname> <dname> <main>"
    + "<<WLS Kernel>> <> <BEA-000360> <Application started in RUNNING mode>";
var pattern = @"\<+(.*?)\>+";
var matches = Regex.Matches(test, pattern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("-{0}-", m.Groups[1]));
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Output (actual matches between `-` chars):

```
-Jun 22, 2012 12:54:18 PM CDT-
-Notice-
-WebLogicServer-
-lname-
-dname-
-main-
-WLS Kernel-
--
-BEA-000360-
-Application started in RUNNING mode-
```

---

```
string test = "####<Jun 22, 2012 12:54:18 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <lname> <dname> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <BEA-000360> <Application started in RUNNING mode>"
    + Environment.NewLine + "####<Jun 23, 2012 12:54:18 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <lname> <dname> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <BEA-000360> <Application started in RUNNING mode>"
    + Environment.NewLine + "####<Jun 24, 2012 12:54:18 PM CDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <lname> <dname> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <BEA-000360> <Application started in RUNNING mode>";

List<Foo> foo = new List<Foo>();
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(test))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string pattern = @"\<+(.*?)\>+";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);

        foo.Add(new Foo
            {
                Timestamp = matches[0].Groups[1].ToString(),
                Field2 = matches[1].Groups[1].ToString()
            });
    }
}
```

Output:

> A list of 3 Foo objects, each with a different Timestamp (Jun 22, Jun
>   23, Jun 24)

Comment: this is great. Really appreciate the help. How may extend the regex to ignore things like "<< >>" in other words double brackets?

Comment: @Warz Please see updated answer, now `<<foo>>` will match `foo`, it this what you wanted?

Comment: Thats perfect, to get each line by itself as i am iterating over each match, thats just m[0] ? i want to handle each line a certain way

Comment: @Warz Not sure to fully understand, but I provided an example that builds a custom Foo object for each line of the log. Hope it's what you expect.

Comment: Wow, thanks again. I used the  CaptureCollection to get each capture from the Match but didn't even think of creating custom class objects for each match.